# Execution rules when using perl's do.

Tags: perl, semantics

I have a question about how perl executes the "do" function.

suppose I have a function that goes something like this:

```
sub foo {
    package bar;
    %bar::h_test = ('b' => 'blah');
}
```

when using strict and warnings, this will run just fine. 
now suppose I have the following perl script, "test.pl":

```
%h_test = ('b' => 'blah');
```

now I can rewrite the previous function as follows:

```
sub foo {
    package bar;
    do ('test.pl');
}
```

it seems that "do" lets me use unqualified names, as long as I keep them in a file. I understand why this makes sense from a design stand-point, since every script out there can't possibly be aware of whoever is calling it. However, I'm not sure what are the precise rules of running code with "do" that allow it.

So, how does it work? Reading the perldoc didn't shed much light on the subject

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think there is something special with `do`. You could have used unqualified name `%h_test` in your first case also

Comment: apparently not, because I get "Global symbol "%h_test" requires explicit package name". which makes sense when using strict.

Comment: Yes you are right. I also get the compile time error if I remove the package name qualifier. Strange. Anyway you could just put `our` in front of the declaration to get rid of the error

Comment: Sure I could. But the point is to understand, not to get rid of compile time errors :)

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)  `use strict 'vars'` does not generate an error if a name is fully qualified. So that should explain the behavior you see?

Comment: Indeed it would. It would not explain the behavior of "do". What seems to happen is that "do" runs the provided block of code in a dynamically scoped package. However, I was unable to find any documentation of this behavior.

Comment: The same [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) also says : *"The effect of this pragma is limited to the current file or scope block"* so that would explain why the `do` works since it is in another file?

Comment: I admit that I've missed this sentence. However, this only half the picture, because when "do" runs, it places h_test in the correct scope, not in the global scope, as if the compilation were taking place where "do" appears (and thus use strict would still apply). 

My current understanding of "do" semantics is the following:


1. run the block as if it appears in a separate file.
2. dynamic scoping still applies.

Comment: I'm unclear why you think `do` is in some way special, as its behaviour is very similar to that of comparable operators like `eval`, `require` etc. The ultimate answer to *"how does it work?"* is of course in the C source of `perl.exe`, but it's unclear what other sort of answer you would like. `do` is *certainly not* special in allowing unqualified names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you do not get a compile time error when you do not declare `%h_test` with `our` in `test.pl`, is that the `use strict` that you have in your main script do not extend to the file `test.pl`. According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html):

> The `strict` pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could behave
>   unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into errors. The
>   effect of this pragma is limited to **the current file** or scope block.

Also note that [the documentation for `do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) says:

> `do './stat.pl'` is largely like:
>
> ```
> eval `cat stat.pl`;
> ```
>
> except that it's more concise, runs no external processes, and keeps
>   track of the current filename for error messages. It also differs in
>   that code evaluated with do FILE **cannot see lexicals in the enclosing
>   scope**

Also, according to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) `use strict 'vars'` does not generate an error if a name is fully qualified. So that explains why you can write `%bar::h_test = ('b' => 'blah')` when using `strict` and whithout declaring the variable with `our`.

Comment: Ok, but do FILE still evaluates the code in the context of the correct package, i.e. h_test should be refereed to  as %bar::h_test everywhere else, even though it was evaluated with "do".  It seems that this understanding is correct.